# Prettier Format On Save - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, prettier, jsprettier

Currently using Prettier to sort my imports for JS files. Everything is working as intended,

Prettierrc file includes:

```
  "importOrder": [ "^components/(.*)$", "^[./]" ],
  "importOrderSeparation": true,
  "importOrderSortSpecifiers": true,
  "importOrderCaseInsensitive": true
```

and everything is sorted when running

```
npx prettier --write "<filepath>"
```

My question is, is there a way to set the formatting to automatically kick-in instead of having to run this request from the CLI? I've seen documents on how to do it in VS Code, but can it be done in Visual Studio 2022 IDE?

Comment: I am looking for exactly this. Did you find a solution?